# UITableViewCell with a custom selectedBackgroundView that is wider than the master view controller on a UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iPad app with an UISplitViewController always displayed on the landscape. Its master controller is a UITableViewController.

I want to have the selectedBackgroundView for the cells on this UITableViewController overflowing into the detail ViewController. Something like this:

[image]

How can I accomplish that? 
If I try to set the red arrow image (that is 342px wide), it gets resized to 320px.
I also tried subclassing UIImageView and overriding setFrame to ignore any calls that try to resize he image, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting all the `clipsToBounds` properties on all the views you can think of to `NO`. Once you get something that works, take them off one by one until you are left with the bare minimum customization needed to achieve your effect.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much :) I'll post my updated code in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Updated on 2013-10-01 to make it work on iOS7)

Kudos to user Erway Software for helping me out.

Here is how I got the code to work:

On the UITableViewController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ...
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"someId"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"];
    SelectionImageView *imageView = [[SelectionImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:imageView];

    [tableView setClipsToBounds:NO];
    [[[cell contentView] superview] setClipsToBounds:NO];
    // ...
}
```

And here is the code for SelectionImageView:

```
@interface SelectionImageView : UIImageView

@end


@implementation SelectionImageView

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    // 342 is the width of image_name
    if (frame.size.width == 342.f) {
        [super setFrame:frame];
    }
}

@end
```